# How can I get IHostingEnvironment from DbContext in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Just for testing, I don't want to do dependency injection from StartUp.cs file.
How can I get IHostingEnvironment from EF Core DBContext.

I take a new asp.net core project with empty template. I have created a dbcontext as below. I want to user Environment.ContentRootPath instead of Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(). But I don't want to do any injection from Startup.cs.

```
public class MyDBContext: DbContext
{

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
              .SetBasePath(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "..\\..\\.."))
              .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
        Configuration = builder.Build();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SQLCN"));// @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;");
    }

    public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Lesson> Lessons { get; set; }
}
```

If I add IHostingEnvironment in dbcontext constructor as below,

```
public class MyDBContext: DbContext
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment env;
    public MyDBContext(IHostingEnvironment env) : base()
    {
        this.env = env;
    }


    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
              .SetBasePath(this.env.ContentRootPath)
              .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
        Configuration = builder.Build();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SQLCN"));// @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;");
    }

    public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Lesson> Lessons { get; set; }
}
```

I got following error when I Add-Migration from Package-Manager console.

```
PM> Add-Migration InitMyDBContext
```

> No parameterless constructor was found on 'MyDBContext'. Either add a
>   parameterless constructor to 'MyDBContext' or add an implementation of
>   'IDbContextFactory' in the same assembly as
>   'MyDBContext'.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] of the problem and expected behavior so that a solution can be derived.

Comment: Dear @Nkosi, I updated my question. Thanks in advanced. This question is not for production problem, just for learning.

Comment: I'm still not clear as to what you mean by not wanting to do any injection from startup? Please clarify that. You can actually inject the IHostingEnvironment directly into the dbcontext's constructor.

Comment: @Nkosi, how to inject IHostingEnvironment directly into the dbcontext?

Comment: just put it in the constructor of the dbcontext

Comment: You should take a read of documentation [Configuring a DbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext). Take specific note of their mention to use db context factory for migration situations

Comment: The original question was answered correctly. Should post new question for the migrations error as that is a different problem all together. I found in 2.2 to get migrations to play nicely I had to run migration command from project where Startup is found as well as have my context reside there as well.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to inject the `IHostingEnvironment` directly into your DbContext's constructor.

```
public class MyDBContext: DbContext {
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment env;
    public MyDBContext(IHostingEnvironment env) : base() {
        this.env = env;
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
        Configuration = builder.Build();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SQLCN"));// @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;");
    }

    public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Lesson> Lessons { get; set; }
}
```

The framework is already aware of the interface.

You add the context as usual. Minus configuration, as you indicated that you don't want to do it in `Startup`

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDBContext>();
```

when initializing the context the framework should inject an implementation of `IHostingEnvironment` into the context based on the presence of the constructor argument.

Comment: I got error "No parameterless constructor was found on 'MyDBContext'. Either add a parameterless constructor to 'MyDBContext' or add an implementation of 'IDbContextFactory' in the same assembly as 'MyDBContext'."

Comment: Dear @Nkosi, yes I read that article. My question is coming after I read that article. I want to read Environment.ContentRootPath from dbcontext class, instead of hard code connection string.

Comment: IHostingEnvironment is deprecated and will be removed in the future. Use IHostEnvironment instead. I hope this helps anyone